# Mac Swift Cocoa - hdiutil: attach failed - Device not configured

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, terminal, zsh

I am creating a MacOS app that automatically installs .dmg's in user *Applications* folder (copies .app in a dmg to */Applications*). But I need to somehow attach the selected .dmg image. I have tried doing this:

```
func dragViewDidReceive(fileURLs: [URL]) {
    for url in fileURLs {
        print(url.path)
        print(shell("hdiutil attach \(url.path)"))
    }
}

func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()

    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

    return output
}
```

But if I select the file (aka call `dragViewDidReceive` function) the dmg will not attach and the output for bash command will be `hdiutil: attach failed - Device not configured`

I also tried using [**ShellOut**](https://github.com/JohnSundell/ShellOut):

```
func dragViewDidReceive(fileURLs: [URL]) {
    for url in fileURLs {
        print(url.path)
        try! shellOut(to: "hdiutil attach \(url.path)")
    }
}
```

Which gives the same error. `hdiutil: attach failed - Device not configured`

Is there any other way how I can attach a .dmg? Or is there any fix for this error using one of these methods?
Thanks

Comment: I would not use `zsh` (or any shell) to do this. Simply sub-launch the hdiutil tool directly. (Shells are for people, not machines.) Works for me.

Comment: For example, I have a custom install helper app that detaches its `.dmg` image after running. The (ObjC) code `[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/hdiutil" arguments:@[@"detach", imgMountPath]]` does the trick.